# Умножение значения переменной в цикле

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace new_time
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int bit = 1; // обьявление + присовение значения переменной
            for (int a = 0; a < 100; a++) // цикл
            {
                    int new_bit = bit * 2; // умножение на 2
                    Console.WriteLine(new_bit); // вывод результата
            }
            Console.ReadKey(); // что бы не закрывалась
        }
    }
}
```

Цель программы сделать вывод значений умноженых на два.
Переменная `bit` изначально `1`.
В цикле по идеи должна умножаться на `2`.
И так каждый раз до значения `100`.

Примерно на такой вывод я расчитываю.

```
2
4
8
16
32
64
```

**Подскажите что не так, и почему мне просто выводит значение `2`**.

Comment: Значение переменной `bit` вы никак не изменяете. А переменная `new_bit` «новая» на каждой итерации цикла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы слегка перемудрили

```cs
int bit = 1;
for (int a = 0; a < 100; a++)
{
    bit *= 2; // bit = bit * 2
    Console.WriteLine(bit);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял =)